# Is it possible to write a function to compose an arbitrary number of SwiftUI `ViewModifier's?

Tags: swift, swiftui, composition

Consider the following `ViewModifier` that applies padding to a particular `View`

```
enum Padding {
    case small
    case medium
    case large
}

private struct PaddingModifier: ViewModifier {
    var edgeSet: Edge.Set = .all
    var size: Padding

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(edgeSet, getSize())
    }

    func getSize() -> CGFloat {
        switch size {
        case .small:
            return 2
        case .medium:
            return 8
        case .large:
            return 16
        }
    }
}
```

To make the `ViewModifier` more readable, typically I'd add an extension function to `View`

```
extension View {
    func padding(_ size: Padding, _ set: Edge.Set = .all) -> some View {
        return modifier(PaddingModifier(edgeSet: set, size: size))
    }
}
```

However, let's say I want to apply this modifier to an arbitrary list of `Edge.Set` values. How can I write a function with the signature `(Padding, [Edge.Set]) -> some View` that applies `PaddingModifier` for each `Edge.Set`?

My first thought was something like below, but `Self` cannot conform to `some View`

```
extension View {
    func padding(_ size: Padding, _ set: Edge.Set = .all) -> some View {
        return modifier(PaddingModifier(edgeSet: set, size: size))
    }

    func padding(_ size: Padding, _ set: [Edge.Set]) -> some View {
        set.reduce(self) { $0.padding(size, $1) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Edge.Set` is a `OptionSet`, so with first modifier it is already possible to code (similarly to built-in `.padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)`)

```
Text("Demo")
   .padding(.small, [.leading, .trailing])
```

it looks like `padding(_ size: Padding, _ set: [Edge.Set])` overthinked.